# Copying Selective Rows from Sheet1 to Sheet2

Tags: vba, excel

Hi all I need to selectively copy entire rows from sheet1 to other sheet. As of now I am using checkboxes to select the rows and then copy the selected rows to sheet of user's choice. But I am facing a bizarre error. For sometime the code runs fine, copying exact data to sheets but after some time it copies erroneous values from nowhere. Can you please help me with this? Pasting the code I am using.

```
Sub Addcheckboxes()
Dim cell, LRow As Single
Dim chkbx As CheckBox
Dim MyLeft, MyTop, MyHeight, MyWidth As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
LRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For cell = 2 To LRow
    If Cells(cell, "A").Value <> "" Then
        MyLeft = Cells(cell, "E").Left
        MyTop = Cells(cell, "E").Top
        MyHeight = Cells(cell, "E").Height
        MyWidth = Cells(cell, "E").Width
        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(MyLeft, MyTop, MyWidth, MyHeight).Select
        With Selection
            .Caption = ""
            .Value = xlOff
            .Display3DShading = False
        End With
    End If
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Sub RemoveCheckboxes()
Dim chkbx As CheckBox
For Each chkbx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    chkbx.Delete
Next
End Sub


Sub CopyRows()
Dim Val As String
Val = InputBox(Prompt:="Sheet name please.", _
          Title:="ENTER SHEET NAME", Default:="Sheet Name here")
For Each chkbx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If chkbx.Value = 1 Then
        For r = 1 To Rows.Count
            If Cells(r, 1).Top = chkbx.Top Then
                With Worksheets(Val)
                    LRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Range("A" & LRow & ":AF" & LRow) = _
                    Worksheets("Usable_Inv_Data").Range("A" & r & ":AF" & r).Value
                End With
                Exit For
            End If
        Next r
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Normal Copy Output:
[image]

Erroneous Copy Output for same values:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a quick comparison of the normal and the erroneous outputs, it looks like some of your cells/columns are not formatted correctly in your destination sheet (where you are "pasting" the values).

For example, your Base Change column in the Normal copy (the value 582.16) is formatted as a General or Number. The same column in the destination sheet is formatted as a date (582.16 converted to a date value in Excel will be 8/4/1901, or 8/4/01, as shown in your screen.

Just make sure the columns are formatted to display the data type you expect. On your destination sheet, select the column, right-click "Format Cells", and then select the appropriate data type.

**---EDIT---**

To automate the formatting, you would have to copy and paste the values, inclusive of the formats. Your code would change from this:

```
With Worksheets(Val)
    LRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range("A" & LRow & ":AF" & LRow) = _
    Worksheets("Usable_Inv_Data").Range("A" & r & ":AF" & r).Value
End With
```

TO

```
With Worksheets(Val)
    LRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Worksheets("Usable_Inv_Data").Range("A" & r & ":AF" & r).Copy
    .Range("A" & LRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. That is the problem but how do I automate that. And why is it occurring in the first place? For initial one or two times everything goes great but suddenly after that the format changes. This is very bizarre

Comment: It shows following error at line 4 of your modified code. http://postimg.org/image/fgobg51c1/

Comment: Can I assume you're not getting that error anymore because you accepted my answer, or are you still seeing it?

Comment: I accepted it because it solved the original problem but the automation thing is still not figured out. Please try to resolve that issue. Thanks.

Comment: are your pages grouped? If they are, are you able to ungroup them (as this will enable the copy/paste)

Comment: How to find out whether they are group or not? Please pardon my novice.

Comment: If, while in a sheet, you look at the top of the excel window and you see the text "[Group]" after the name of the file, then that sheet is grouped. You can ungroup the sheets by creating a new sheet or selecting a sheet that's not part of the group (the tabs at the bottom of the excel window will appear lighter/whiter for grouped sheets than for non-grouped sheets)

Comment: I think they are ungrouped as there is no text saying 'Grouped'

Answer (score 1):

I have added the checkbox with LinkedCell property. This helps to identify the rows when checkbox is checked.
Also i have added a function check_worksheet_exists which will check if the workbook exist.

```
Sub Addcheckboxes()
Dim cell, LRow As Single
Dim chkbx As CheckBox
Dim MyLeft, MyTop, MyHeight, MyWidth As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
LRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

For cell = 2 To LRow
    If Cells(cell, "A").Value <> "" Then
        MyLeft = Cells(cell, "E").Left
        MyTop = Cells(cell, "E").Top
        MyHeight = Cells(cell, "E").Height
        MyWidth = Cells(cell, "E").Width
        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(MyLeft, MyTop, MyWidth, MyHeight).Select
        With Selection
            .Caption = ""
            .Value = xlOff
            .Display3DShading = False
            .LinkedCell = Cells(cell, "AZ").Address
        End With
    End If
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Sub RemoveCheckboxes()
Dim chkbx As CheckBox
For Each chkbx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    chkbx.Delete
Next
End Sub


Sub CopyRows()

    Dim Val As String
    Dim row As Long

    Val = InputBox(Prompt:="Sheet name please.", Title:="ENTER SHEET NAME", Default:="Sheet Name here")

    If check_worksheet_exists(ThisWorkbook, Val, False) = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each chkbx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If chkbx.Value = 1 Then
            row = Range(chkbx.LinkedCell).row

            With Worksheets(Val)
                LRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
                .Range("A" & LRow & ":AF" & LRow) = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & row & ":AF" & row).Value
            End With

        End If
    Next
End Sub




Function check_worksheet_exists(tBook As Workbook, ByVal check_sheet As String, Optional no_warning As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim wkSht As Worksheet
    Set wkSht = tBook.Sheets(check_sheet)

    If Not wkSht Is Nothing Then
        check_worksheet_exists = True
    ElseIf wkSht Is Nothing And no_warning = False Then
        MsgBox "'" & check_sheet & "' sheet does not exist", vbCritical, "Error"
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the error is still there. Can you please explain what more did you add?

Comment: @VikasBansal  At which line & what is the error description? I already explained what i have added.

Answer (score 0):

i cannot immediately see the errors you refer to, unless you are referring to the sequences of hash-signs ###? These just indicate that the columns aren't wide enough.

```
Worksheets(Val).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

BTW I don't think Val is a sensible variable name ;)

Comment: Thank you for comment. Have a look at base charge. The values are different in two images, it should be the same. And where should I put this autofit line code in my program? Thank you.

Comment: It is still the same :(